# VBA - Ungroup a Table in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am looking for an automated way to ungroup a table in power point to create shapes.

I found the following tutorial:

[Tutorial](http://www.indezine.com/products/powerpoint/learn/tables/2013/ungroup-a-table-in-ppt.html)

Further, I wanted to record the macro(I am quite new to vba), however in power point 2010 the macro recorder is not available any more. Any suggestions, how to create the above tutorial in vba?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example to get you started. Be sure to select the table you want to work with first.

```
Sub PasteAndUngroup()
    Dim oSh As Shape
    Dim oSl As Slide

    Set oSh = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
    Set oSl = oSh.Parent

    oSh.Copy

    Set oSh = oSl.Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteEnhancedMetafile)(1)

    oSh.Ungroup

End Sub
```